# Using AES encryption in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, rijndaelmanaged

I can't seem to find a nice clean example of using AES 128 bit encryption.

Does anyone have some sample code?

Comment: Pretty good article on this here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt

Answer (score 143):

If you just want to use the built-in crypto provider RijndaelManaged, check out the following help article (it also has a simple code sample):

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx

And just in case you need the sample in a hurry, here it is in all its plagiarized glory:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace RijndaelManaged_Example
{
    class RijndaelExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {

                string original = "Here is some data to encrypt!";

                // Create a new instance of the RijndaelManaged 
                // class.  This generates a new key and initialization  
                // vector (IV). 
                using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
                {

                    myRijndael.GenerateKey();
                    myRijndael.GenerateIV();
                    // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes. 
                    byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(original, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

                    // Decrypt the bytes to a string. 
                    string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

                    //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
                    Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", original);
                    Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
            // with the specified key and IV. 
            using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rijAlg.Key = Key;
                rijAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption. 
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {

                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }


            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream. 
            return encrypted;

        }

        static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold 
            // the decrypted text. 
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
            // with the specified key and IV. 
            using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rijAlg.Key = Key;
                rijAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption. 
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return plaintext;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this post is quite old, but just a side note for those coming across this. The WinApp code in the linked article titled "Keep Your Data Secure with the New Advanced Encryption Standard" doesn't work.

Comment: @CODe - can you be more specific?  Does it not compile?  Is there a bug?

Comment: The application runs fine, but it doesn't decrypt. It spits out a string that looks very much like the encrypted version instead, the unencrypted isn't anywhere close to the original version.

Comment: Your code doesn't store the IV along with the ciphertext, making it hard to use correctly, and easy to abuse. An IV isn't a secondary key, it should be randomly generated for each encryption, and stored alongside the ciphertext.

Comment: For future readers:  I have updated the code sample here with updated code from the sample on MSDN

Comment: Also:  Don't forget that you're most likely dangerously bad at cryptography.  http://happybearsoftware.com/you-are-dangerously-bad-at-cryptography.html

Comment: As stated in MSDN you shouldn't be using RijndaelManaged anymore. The Rijndael class is the predecessor of the Aes algorithm, therefor use Aes.

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih Can you please link to the MSDN content that states that?  

In the remarks of this article, Microsoft states that "The AES algorithm is essentially the Rijndael symmetric algorithm with a fixed block size and iteration count. This class functions the same way as the RijndaelManaged class but limits blocks to 128 bits and does not allow feedback modes." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx

Comment: Sure, there you go. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx Take a look at remarks. You can use rijndael but it could lead to compatibility issues, when you channge settings. Therefor I would use Aes-Class if you want to encrypt with AES(FIPS-197)

Comment: @EricJ. The `using ()` block automatically disposes the myRijndael object (and every other RijndaelManaged object in this example).
Perhaps your comment was for an earlier version of the answer, or the link were showing bad examples, but that's not the case today.

Answer (score 54):

I've recently had to bump up against this again in my own project - and wanted to share the somewhat simpler code that I've been using, as this question and series of answers kept coming up in my searches.

I'm not going to get into the security concerns around how often to update things like your *Salt* and *Initialization Vector* - that's a topic for a security forum, and there are some great resources out there to look at. This is simply a block of code to implement `AesManaged` in C#.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Your.Namespace.Security {
    public static class Cryptography {
        #region Settings

        private static int _iterations = 2;
        private static int _keySize = 256;

        private static string _hash     = "SHA1";
        private static string _salt     = "aselrias38490a32"; // Random
        private static string _vector   = "8947az34awl34kjq"; // Random

        #endregion

        public static string Encrypt(string value, string password) {
            return Encrypt<AesManaged>(value, password);
        }
        public static string Encrypt<T>(string value, string password) 
                where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new() {
            byte[] vectorBytes = GetBytes<ASCIIEncoding>(_vector);
            byte[] saltBytes = GetBytes<ASCIIEncoding>(_salt);
            byte[] valueBytes = GetBytes<UTF8Encoding>(value);

            byte[] encrypted;
            using (T cipher = new T()) {
                PasswordDeriveBytes _passwordBytes = 
                    new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, _hash, _iterations);
                byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(_keySize / 8);

                cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = cipher.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes)) {
                    using (MemoryStream to = new MemoryStream()) {
                        using (CryptoStream writer = new CryptoStream(to, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                            writer.Write(valueBytes, 0, valueBytes.Length);
                            writer.FlushFinalBlock();
                            encrypted = to.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
                cipher.Clear();
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string value, string password) {
            return Decrypt<AesManaged>(value, password);
        }
        public static string Decrypt<T>(string value, string password) where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new() {
            byte[] vectorBytes = GetBytes<ASCIIEncoding>(_vector);
            byte[] saltBytes = GetBytes<ASCIIEncoding>(_salt);
            byte[] valueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

            byte[] decrypted;
            int decryptedByteCount = 0;

            using (T cipher = new T()) {
                PasswordDeriveBytes _passwordBytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, _hash, _iterations);
                byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(_keySize / 8);

                cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                try {
                    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = cipher.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes)) {
                        using (MemoryStream from = new MemoryStream(valueBytes)) {
                            using (CryptoStream reader = new CryptoStream(from, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                                decrypted = new byte[valueBytes.Length];
                                decryptedByteCount = reader.Read(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    return String.Empty;
                }

                cipher.Clear();
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted, 0, decryptedByteCount);
        }

    }
}
```

The code is very simple to use. It literally just requires the following:

```
string encrypted = Cryptography.Encrypt(data, "testpass");
string decrypted = Cryptography.Decrypt(encrypted, "testpass");
```

By default, the implementation uses AesManaged - but you could actually also insert any other `SymmetricAlgorithm`. A list of the available `SymmetricAlgorithm` inheritors for .NET 4.5 can be found at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.aspx

As of the time of this post, the current list includes:

- `AesManaged`
- `RijndaelManaged`
- `DESCryptoServiceProvider`
- `RC2CryptoServiceProvider`
- `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider`

To use `RijndaelManaged` with the code above, as an example, you would use:

```
string encrypted = Cryptography.Encrypt<RijndaelManaged>(dataToEncrypt, password);
string decrypted = Cryptography.Decrypt<RijndaelManaged>(encrypted, password);
```

I hope this is helpful to someone out there.

Comment: I get an error of: "Error The name 'GetBytes' does not exist in the current context." How can I solve this? EDIT: Fixed it by using ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes and UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes.

Comment: I'm afraid not, @DeveloperX. The code relies on the .NET Cryptography libraries, so my guess is that either you'd have to find an equivalent set of libraries in Java, or roll your own. :(

Comment: Hi Troy, I have the same questions like cvocvo said. The message is `The name 'GetBytes' does not exist in the current context`. Can I ask you what version of .Net framework that you use?

Comment: Johnny - use ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes and UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes. Therefore vector bytes would be byte[] vectorBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_vector);

Comment: Your code is wrong, in Decrypt change "valuebytes" line to the following: ` byte[] valueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);` . The reason for this is because in Encrypt you converted ToBase64 so now you need to ConvertFromBase64String in Decrypt, otherwise you get invalid length error.

Comment: @Euthyphro - I reverted to the previous version of the code, which is what I actually used when I wrote this 4 years ago. I had recently updated it, based on `user1012500`'s comment - but didn't retest it at all.

Comment: Updating IV is **every** message, not a debate, just plain how you use AES-CBC, this answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: @jbtule: Let's say we want to encrypt the contents of a particular column in a database table, a `notes` field, say, so that the data in the field is "encrypted at rest". The note will have to be decrypted whenever a user needs to read it. Must the IV be different for each record? I am not really up to speed yet on this subject.  What do you mean by "message"? Is that a catch-all term for "item that needs to be encrypted"?

Comment: @Tim More than just a random IV for every record, the IV should be unpredictable every time new data is written. If the encrypted notes are mutable, when you re-encrypt the data with some changes to the same record, you need to generate a new random IV. Typically this is merely done on encrypt by just generating a random IV (or using the random one .net automatically creates) and prepending it to your ciphertext, then popping it off and using it in decrypt.

Comment: -1.  "not going to get into the security concerns" on a question about encryption.  People are going to use this code in their applications and because it "works" it has a ton of votes and they will trust it. The IV needs to be randomly generated for *each* function call.  It should not be used as a password.  You append it to the output, and then read it back in before decryption.  The goal of the IV is to stop information from being leaked by the similar inputs.  Try this:  Encrypt "Hello" and "Hello1"  you will notice they have very similar outputs.  Using a unique IV will fix that.

Comment: The `Cryptography.Encrypt(data, "testpass");` I must storage along with the data encrypted or has to be something internal static "testpass"?

Comment: @troy I'm sorry to ask after so long but what do the parameters do?  I am using this for a password and I just need to send the password and get the encrypted version to store in the database or send the unencrypted version to return the encrypted version to store in the database.

Comment: 2-way encryption requires you to use a password as part of the encryption, so that you can then use the same password again to decrypt later. The first parameter is the value you want to encrypt - and the second parameter is the value you want to use again, later, to decrypt. I think it may be confusing to you because the _type_ of value you are encrypting _is_ a password.

Answer (score 13):

Look at sample in here..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=VS.100).aspx#Y2262

The example on MSDN does not run normally (an error occurs) because there is **no initial value** of **Initial Vector(iv)** and **Key**. I add 2 line code and now work normally.

More details see below:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace AES_TESTER
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          try
          {

            string original = "Here is some data to encrypt!";
            MessageBox.Show("Original:   " + original);

            // Create a new instance of the RijndaelManaged
            // class.  This generates a new key and initialization 
            // vector (IV).
            using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                 myRijndael.GenerateKey();
                 myRijndael.GenerateIV();

                // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
                byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(original, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (byte item in encrypted)
                {
                   s.Append(item.ToString("X2") + " ");
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Encrypted:   " + s);

                // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
                string decrypted = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

                //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
                MessageBox.Show("Decrypted:    " + decrypted);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create an RijndaelManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }


        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;

    }

    static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an RijndaelManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return plaintext;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to set the value of the initial vector and the keys before calling the function encrypt and decrypt, with this line code:  myRijndael.GenerateKey();
myRijndael.GenerateIV();

Comment: You can change AES Mode with changing this line code rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; Eg to rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CFB; or rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; Look at [link] http://www.inconteam.com/software-development/41-encryption/55-aes-test-vectors if you want to test the AES, whether it is functioning normally or not.

Answer (score 9):

Using AES or implementing AES?  To use AES, there is the System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged class.

Comment: yes I understand but i cant seem to figure out how to implement 128 Bit CFB with 32 characters as the key(nibble). Do u kknow how to edit the above code. I jsut got started. Seem to need more help

Answer (score 8):

For a more complete example that performs key derivation in addition to the AES encryption, see the answer and links posted in [Getting AES encryption to work across Javascript and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149611/getting-slowaes-and-rijndaelmanaged-class-in-net-to-play-together).

**EDIT**
a side note: [Javascript Cryptography considered harmful.](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) Worth the read.

Answer (score 8):

```
//Code to encrypt Data :   
 public byte[] encryptdata(byte[] bytearraytoencrypt, string key, string iv)  
         {  
           AesCryptoServiceProvider dataencrypt = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();  
           //Block size : Gets or sets the block size, in bits, of the cryptographic operation.  
           dataencrypt.BlockSize = 128;  
           //KeySize: Gets or sets the size, in bits, of the secret key  
           dataencrypt.KeySize = 128;  
           //Key: Gets or sets the symmetric key that is used for encryption and decryption.  
           dataencrypt.Key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);  
           //IV : Gets or sets the initialization vector (IV) for the symmetric algorithm  
           dataencrypt.IV = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);  
           //Padding: Gets or sets the padding mode used in the symmetric algorithm  
           dataencrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;  
           //Mode: Gets or sets the mode for operation of the symmetric algorithm  
           dataencrypt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;  
           //Creates a symmetric AES encryptor object using the current key and initialization vector (IV).  
           ICryptoTransform crypto1 = dataencrypt.CreateEncryptor(dataencrypt.Key, dataencrypt.IV);  
           //TransformFinalBlock is a special function for transforming the last block or a partial block in the stream.   
           //It returns a new array that contains the remaining transformed bytes. A new array is returned, because the amount of   
           //information returned at the end might be larger than a single block when padding is added.  
           byte[] encrypteddata = crypto1.TransformFinalBlock(bytearraytoencrypt, 0, bytearraytoencrypt.Length);  
           crypto1.Dispose();  
           //return the encrypted data  
           return encrypteddata;  
         }  

//code to decrypt data
    private byte[] decryptdata(byte[] bytearraytodecrypt, string key, string iv)  
     {  

       AesCryptoServiceProvider keydecrypt = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();  
       keydecrypt.BlockSize = 128;  
       keydecrypt.KeySize = 128;  
       keydecrypt.Key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);  
       keydecrypt.IV = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);  
       keydecrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;  
       keydecrypt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;  
       ICryptoTransform crypto1 = keydecrypt.CreateDecryptor(keydecrypt.Key, keydecrypt.IV);  

       byte[] returnbytearray = crypto1.TransformFinalBlock(bytearraytodecrypt, 0, bytearraytodecrypt.Length);  
       crypto1.Dispose();  
       return returnbytearray;  
     }
```

Comment: Beware: I see missing Dispose() statements.

Comment: Hello! Any particular reason to use PKCS7 padding over the other choices? From what I read it is inferior to OAEP padding, which is for some reason unavailable for AES. Is PKCS7 safer in AES than in RSA?

Answer (score 5):

***http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt***

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
```

```
public byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;
            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    return encryptedBytes;
}

public byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    byte[] decryptedBytes = null;
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;
            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    return decryptedBytes;
}
```

Comment: This post was very helpful to me, but beware this is the bare bones code. In the article it shows how to prepend the salt to the cyphertext and use SecureString, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code, maybe useful.
1.Create New C# Project and add follows code to Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ExampleCrypto
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strOriginalData = string.Empty;
            string strEncryptedData = string.Empty;
            string strDecryptedData = string.Empty;

            strOriginalData = "this is original data 1234567890"; // your original data in here
            MessageBox.Show("ORIGINAL DATA:\r\n" + strOriginalData);

            clsCrypto aes = new clsCrypto();
            aes.IV = "this is your IV";     // your IV
            aes.KEY = "this is your KEY";    // your KEY      
            strEncryptedData = aes.Encrypt(strOriginalData, CipherMode.CBC);    // your cipher mode
            MessageBox.Show("ENCRYPTED DATA:\r\n" + strEncryptedData);

            strDecryptedData = aes.Decrypt(strEncryptedData, CipherMode.CBC);
            MessageBox.Show("DECRYPTED DATA:\r\n" + strDecryptedData);
        }

    }
}
```

2.Create clsCrypto.cs and copy paste follows code in your class and run your code. I used MD5 to generated Initial Vector(IV) and KEY of AES.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;

namespace ExampleCrypto
{
    public class clsCrypto
    {
        private string _KEY = string.Empty;
        protected internal string KEY
        {
            get
            {
                return _KEY;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    _KEY = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private string _IV = string.Empty;
        protected internal string IV
        {
            get
            {
                return _IV;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    _IV = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private string CalcMD5(string strInput)
        {
            string strOutput = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInput))
            {
                try
                {
                    StringBuilder strHex = new StringBuilder();
                    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
                    {
                        byte[] bytArText = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strInput);
                        byte[] bytArHash = md5.ComputeHash(bytArText);
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytArHash.Length; i++)
                        {
                            strHex.Append(bytArHash[i].ToString("X2"));
                        }
                        strOutput = strHex.ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return strOutput;
        }

        private byte[] GetBytesFromHexString(string strInput)
        {
            byte[] bytArOutput = new byte[] { };
            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInput)) && strInput.Length % 2 == 0)
            {
                SoapHexBinary hexBinary = null;
                try
                {
                    hexBinary = SoapHexBinary.Parse(strInput);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                bytArOutput = hexBinary.Value;
            }
            return bytArOutput;
        }

        private byte[] GenerateIV()
        {
            byte[] bytArOutput = new byte[] { };
            try
            {
                string strIV = CalcMD5(IV);
                bytArOutput = GetBytesFromHexString(strIV);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return bytArOutput;
        }

        private byte[] GenerateKey()
        {
            byte[] bytArOutput = new byte[] { };
            try
            {
                string strKey = CalcMD5(KEY);
                bytArOutput = GetBytesFromHexString(strKey);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return bytArOutput;
        }

        protected internal string Encrypt(string strInput, CipherMode cipherMode)
        {
            string strOutput = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInput))
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] bytePlainText = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strInput);
                    using (RijndaelManaged rijManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
                    {
                        rijManaged.Mode = cipherMode;
                        rijManaged.BlockSize = 128;
                        rijManaged.KeySize = 128;
                        rijManaged.IV = GenerateIV();
                        rijManaged.Key = GenerateKey();
                        rijManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                        ICryptoTransform icpoTransform = rijManaged.CreateEncryptor(rijManaged.Key, rijManaged.IV);
                        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream cpoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, icpoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                            {
                                cpoStream.Write(bytePlainText, 0, bytePlainText.Length);
                                cpoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            }
                            strOutput = Encoding.Default.GetString(memStream.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return strOutput;
        }

        protected internal string Decrypt(string strInput, CipherMode cipherMode)
        {
            string strOutput = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInput))
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] byteCipherText = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strInput);
                    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[strInput.Length];
                    using (RijndaelManaged rijManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
                    {
                        rijManaged.Mode = cipherMode;
                        rijManaged.BlockSize = 128;
                        rijManaged.KeySize = 128;
                        rijManaged.IV = GenerateIV();
                        rijManaged.Key = GenerateKey();
                        rijManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                        ICryptoTransform icpoTransform = rijManaged.CreateDecryptor(rijManaged.Key, rijManaged.IV);
                        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(byteCipherText))
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream cpoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, icpoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                cpoStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
                            }
                            strOutput = Encoding.Default.GetString(byteBuffer);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return strOutput;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use password from text box like key...
With this code you can encrypt/decrypt text, picture, word document, pdf....

```
 public class Rijndael
{
    private byte[] key;
    private readonly byte[] vector = { 255, 64, 191, 111, 23, 3, 113, 119, 231, 121, 252, 112, 79, 32, 114, 156 };

    ICryptoTransform EnkValue, DekValue;

    public Rijndael(byte[] key)
    {
        this.key = key;
        RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
        rm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        EnkValue = rm.CreateEncryptor(key, vector);
        DekValue = rm.CreateDecryptor(key, vector);
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] byte)
    {

        byte[] enkByte= byte;
        byte[] enkNewByte;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, EnkValue, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(enkByte, 0, enkByte.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                ms.Position = 0;
                enkNewByte= new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Read(enkNewByte, 0, enkNewByte.Length);
            }
        }
        return enkNeyByte;
    }

    public byte[] Dekrypt(byte[] enkByte)
    {
        byte[] dekByte;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, DekValue, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(enkByte, 0, enkByte.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                ms.Position = 0;
                dekByte= new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Read(dekByte, 0, dekByte.Length);
            }
        }
        return dekByte;
    }
}
```

Convert password from text box to byte array...

```
private byte[] ConvertPasswordToByte(string password)
    {
        byte[] key = new byte[32];
        for (int i = 0; i < passwprd.Length; i++)
        {
            key[i] = Convert.ToByte(passwprd[i]);
        }
        return key;
    }
```

Comment: Possible IndexOutOfRangeException in ConvertPasswordToByte if password has more than 32 characters.

Comment: Your IV should be random and stored along with the cypher text (but not encrypted).

Answer (score 2):

here is a neat and clean code to understand AES 256 algorithm implemented in C#
call Encrypt function as `encryptedstring = cryptObj.Encrypt(username, "AGARAMUDHALA", "EZHUTHELLAM", "SHA1", 3, "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8", 256);`

```
public class Crypt
{
    public string Encrypt(string passtext, string passPhrase, string saltV, string hashstring, int Iterations, string initVect, int keysize)
    {
        string functionReturnValue = null;
        // Convert strings into byte arrays.
        // Let us assume that strings only contain ASCII codes.
        // If strings include Unicode characters, use Unicode, UTF7, or UTF8
        // encoding.
        byte[] initVectorBytes = null;
        initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVect);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = null;
        saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltV);

        // Convert our plaintext into a byte array.
        // Let us assume that plaintext contains UTF8-encoded characters.
        byte[] plainTextBytes = null;
        plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passtext);
        // First, we must create a password, from which the key will be derived.
        // This password will be generated from the specified passphrase and
        // salt value. The password will be created using the specified hash
        // algorithm. Password creation can be done in several iterations.
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = default(PasswordDeriveBytes);
        password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashstring, Iterations);
        // Use the password to generate pseudo-random bytes for the encryption
        // key. Specify the size of the key in bytes (instead of bits).
        byte[] keyBytes = null;
        keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize/8);
        // Create uninitialized Rijndael encryption object.
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = default(RijndaelManaged);
        symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

        // It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
        // (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        // Generate encryptor from the existing key bytes and initialization
        // vector. Key size will be defined based on the number of the key
        // bytes.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = default(ICryptoTransform);
        encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);

        // Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
        MemoryStream memoryStream = default(MemoryStream);
        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        // Define cryptographic stream (always use Write mode for encryption).
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = default(CryptoStream);
        cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        // Start encrypting.
        cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

        // Finish encrypting.
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        // Convert our encrypted data from a memory stream into a byte array.
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = null;
        cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        // Close both streams.
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();

        // Convert encrypted data into a base64-encoded string.
        string cipherText = null;
        cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);

        functionReturnValue = cipherText;
        return functionReturnValue;
    }
    public string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase, string saltValue, string hashAlgorithm, int passwordIterations, string initVector, int keySize)
    {
        string functionReturnValue = null;

        // Convert strings defining encryption key characteristics into byte
        // arrays. Let us assume that strings only contain ASCII codes.
        // If strings include Unicode characters, use Unicode, UTF7, or UTF8
        // encoding.


            byte[] initVectorBytes = null;
            initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);

            byte[] saltValueBytes = null;
            saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);

            // Convert our ciphertext into a byte array.
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = null;
            cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

            // First, we must create a password, from which the key will be
            // derived. This password will be generated from the specified
            // passphrase and salt value. The password will be created using
            // the specified hash algorithm. Password creation can be done in
            // several iterations.
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = default(PasswordDeriveBytes);
            password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations);

            // Use the password to generate pseudo-random bytes for the encryption
            // key. Specify the size of the key in bytes (instead of bits).
            byte[] keyBytes = null;
            keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);

            // Create uninitialized Rijndael encryption object.
            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = default(RijndaelManaged);
            symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

            // It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
            // (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            // Generate decryptor from the existing key bytes and initialization
            // vector. Key size will be defined based on the number of the key
            // bytes.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = default(ICryptoTransform);
            decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);

            // Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
            MemoryStream memoryStream = default(MemoryStream);
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);

            // Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = default(CryptoStream);
            cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            // Since at this point we don't know what the size of decrypted data
            // will be, allocate the buffer long enough to hold ciphertext;
            // plaintext is never longer than ciphertext.
            byte[] plainTextBytes = null;
            plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length + 1];

            // Start decrypting.
            int decryptedByteCount = 0;
            decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

            // Close both streams.
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();

            // Convert decrypted data into a string.
            // Let us assume that the original plaintext string was UTF8-encoded.
            string plainText = null;
            plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);

            // Return decrypted string.
            functionReturnValue = plainText;


        return functionReturnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Clean and Crisp. I tried with cryptObj.Encrypt(username, "TAMIZHAN TAMIZHAN DHAAN", "VAZHGATAMIZH", "SHA1", 3, "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8", 256). It worked.

Comment: why is the class not static?