# Code for encrypting/decrypting data using CFB 128 bit AES Encryption

Tags: aes

Can anyone give me code or links for sample 128 bit CFB type of AES IMplementation.

Can it be written using .Net. If so can you please explain how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/c-implementations-of-aes-encryption) answer on SO might lead you in the right direction.  Hope it helps!

Update: From the example linked above (I don't want to copy-pasta @Dan Esparza's entire answer) I believe you'd just make a call to:

```
myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CFB
```

To get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: i want to have CFB version is it possible to edit the code to get that. The one u have mentioned is CBC

Comment: yes I understand but i cant seem to figure out how to implement 128 Bit CFB with 32 characters as the key(nibble). Do u kknow how to edit the above code. I jsut got started. Seem to need more help