# Should I use the bouncy castle libraries or the ones included in Android for AES

Tags: android, encryption, aes, bouncycastle

I'm writing an android app where I need to use AES. Is it better to use the bouncy castle libraries or should I just stick with what is included in default android libraries?

Comment: The bouncycastle libraries are built-in.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the built in ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question might be phrased better the other way - why would you not use the built in libraries?

Anyway, here's a helpful link with some code samples: [Encryption compatible between Android and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090765/encryption-compatable-between-android-and-c)

Comment: I had come accross the code snippet for android before, but thank you for the link.