# Encryption/Decryption in Android

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I have done encryption in android with a static password i.e. "encrypt". The encryption works fine and encrypts the data. But when i try to decrypt the encrypted text it does not show. The code to decrypt is as follow.

```
public String decrypt(String msg, String inputPassword) throws Exception{
    SecretKeySpec key= generateKey(inputPassword);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decodedValue= Base64.decode(msg, Base64.DEFAULT);

    /*If this line is present the encrypted message is not seen*/
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(Base64.decode(decodedValue, 
Base64.DEFAULT));
    String decryptedValue = new String(decodedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

When the code (below the comment) is enabled. The message is not displayed. But when the line is commented. This is shown in the message box

[After the code is commented.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC7cc.png)

This is the encrypt and key generate methods.

```
public String encrypt(String message, String inputPassword) throws Exception{
    SecretKeySpec key = generateKey(inputPassword);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
    c.init(c.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encryptedValue;
}

//For generating key for encryption
public SecretKeySpec generateKey(String inputPassword) throws  Exception{
    final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] bytes = inputPassword.getBytes("UTF-8");
    digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    byte[] key = digest.digest();
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    return secretKeySpec;
}
```

The log is follow 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOaZj.png)

Also the API level is not maintained... I don't know where to setup this as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B34zn.png)

Comment: is the exception raised?

Comment: The exception handler shows the error in this line                                           
byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue);

Comment: are you using the same password while encrypting and decryption?
if not you are not going to get the desired output. Test the code by creating a normal java class.

Comment: @DurgeshKumar Currently the password is static.

Comment: kindly paste the code here

Comment: Why do you base64-decode your message twice in your decrypt method? I don't see you encode twice in the encrypt method after all...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes. Even when i use that one time. The error and the problem is same.

Comment: Well, if I use `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"` this works perfectly. Of course, since you've forgot to specify the `AES` constant but do not use an IV, I presume you are using ECB mode or just `"AES"` as cipher.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try changing this

```
String decryptedValue = new String(decodedValue)
```

to this

```
String decryptedValue = new String(decodedValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

And for your error, try changing to this

```
c.doFinal(Base64.decode(decodedValue, Base64.DEFAULT))
```

Comment: The message is not displayed when the is not commented.  After this line nothing executes                                   
 byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue);

Comment: still the same error. There seems to have problem in decrypt method . It says that it doesnot take API less than 24 or so

Comment: Maybe this can be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433529/android-4-2-broke-my-encrypt-decrypt-code-and-the-provided-solutions-dont-work