# How to encrypt variable length text in PHP and C#?

Tags: c#, php, cryptography

For a game I am currently making I am in need of encrypting a variable length string (this could be a short as 10 characters or a full XML document) in C# and then sending this to a PHP script which decrypts and processes the information.  I am unfortunately completely in the dark when it comes to cryptography and am having trouble finding something that can suite my needs in this case.   Is there a library which can do this kind of variable length encryption across multiple platforms such as this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), sometimes called Rijndael, might be a choice for you.  It's a standard created by the National Institute of Standards and Technology, an agency of the US government.

It's available in PHP using the [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) extension, and there seems to be a [managed library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) built in to the .Net framework.  [See this previous SO question for more on C#'s implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/c-implementations-of-aes-encryption).  I know little about C# and .Net, but the answer there has 23 votes, so is likely to be on to something.  (Edit: @Fun Mun Pieng's answer contains a reference to AES itself, and might be more up to date or otherwise useful than the post I linked.)

AES is a block cypher, meaning that it operates best on lengths of text of a specific set of lengths.  There are multiple [operation modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) and [padding schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) that you'll want to read up on and select.  If you use the same operation mode and padding on both sides, you should have perfect interoperability.

Keep in mind that AES is a symmetric cypher.  This means that the same key is used to both encrypt and decrypt.  It might not be the best choice for you.  If your users gain access to the key, the encryption becomes worthless.

[Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) might be a better choice for you.  It uses two keys instead of one.  Data encrypted using the public key can only be decrypted by the private key.  This means that you don't need to worry too much about the public key falling into the wrong hands, as no data can actually be decrypted about it.  It may allow troublesome users to still craft legit-looking messages, though.

PHP's best option for public-key cryptography is the [standard OpenSSL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php), which uses the industry standard RSA system.  A quick look at Google [suggests that there's also native .Net support for RSA as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx).  Like AES, you may need to worry about modes of operation or padding, but again you should get complete interoperation by using the same methodology on both sides.  The one possible annoyance will be initial key creation, and how each side wants to store private and public keys.

Answer (score 0):

For the C# part, you could use the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace. Eg:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Aes aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create();
System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform enc = aes.CreateEncryptor();
// byte[] input;
// byte[] output = new output[512]
int size = enc.TransformBlock(input, 0, input.Length, output, 0);
```

I have no idea how to do it for the PHP end, but I'm sure you can find a way to decrypt from standard algorithms such as DES, AES, RSA. And remember to pass the key.

For your case, I guess [asymmetric encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) is more suitable.