# Decrypting AES encrypted file in C# with java

Tags: c#, java, android, encryption, aes

I have the following problem. I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/c-implementations-of-aes-encryption) code to encrypt a sample text in C#, and want to decrypt it in java. I use the following java code.

```
byte[] IV = { 65, 1, 2, 23, 4, 5, 6, 7, 32, 21, 10, 11, 12, 13, 84, 45 };
byte[] KEY = { 0, 42, 2, 54, 4, 45, 6, 7, 65, 9, 54, 11, 12, 13, 60, 15 };
byte baData[] = new byte[1024];
int iRead = 0;

SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance ("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV));

File file = new File("/sdcard", "SAMPLE.txt");

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
iRead = in.read(baData, 0, baData.length);

String strResult = new String(cipher.doFinal(baData, 0, baData.length));
```

I obviously use the same IV and KEY values above as in the C# sample. The above java code runs on an android device, and the encrypted binary file is the SAMPLE.txt on it's sdcard.
The problem is I don't get the correct data after decrypting it. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

- What encoding are you using to convert the text data into binary before encrypting it? Your current use of the string constructor will use the platform default encoding - almost never a good idea
- You're *assuming* that a single call to `read()` will read everything - you're not actually using the value of `iRead` later
- You're *assuming* that all the data will fit in a 1024-byte buffer

It's hard to know which of those is causing the problem.

I would strongly suggest that you use a `CipherInputStream` to wrap your `FileInputStream`, and then wrap an `InputStreamReader` around that, using the appropriate encoding. You could then use something like Guava's `CharStreams.toString()` method to read everything from the `InputStreamReader` into a string.

EDIT: As noted in comments, while all of these *are* potential problems, there's also the matter of the code currently creating the `Cipher` in *encryption* mode rather than *decryption* mode.

Comment: You're right about those points, but I'm actually testing with a sample data which I know will be small. But the real problem turned out to be that I am using Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE instead of Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE. A stupid mistake, but I realized it just now as I was revising your points. Thanks for your help Jon.

Comment: @Sebouh: I've edited my answer to note that, for future readers.