# Producing Product Key for Softwares

Tags: c#, encryption, authorization

I am looking simple encryption functionality for my company's products. I am not looking for complicated encryptions. Just simple keys to keep things okay for both side, my company and customers. 
Company will have C# application to produce keys, then we will send keys to customers. When user opened key producer application, he/she will select products we sold, and type customer key. And program will produce the key.

```
Customer id is an integer of 6 characters. (Example: 103499)

Product id are string(can be both integer and char) of 4 characters.(Example: PRD3)

Also program will have an expiration date. (Example: 10/10/2013)
```

Once customers enter this key, product updates itself to use enabled function in the key.

I don't have much information about encryption, so i would appreciate your help.

Regards

Comment: You can use aes encryption.
Takea look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp

Comment: The keys are pretty short. What prevents users from trying keys in order until a valid one is found?

Comment: @ntoskrnl  customer and special product ids will be entered at our side.After the encryption,the customer will recieve long key.Customer wont be able to see customer id and special product id.

Comment: @user220255 thanks aes encryption worked really well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a public/private key method, this way you'll have a public key and the product key will act as the private one.

This article should be a good start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e9ft273.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I decided making it with AES encryption and it worked well for my purpose. Thanks for your asistance!

I used [Using AES encryption in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp) topic as reference.