# Simple AES Code - Compiler Can't find GetBytes<ASCIIEncoding>?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am trying to use a simplified AES Encrypt/Decrypt that I found [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp) but I am getting compile errors on the GetBytes<> calls? What form of GetBytes do I have to use to get this to work? In other words, how can I get this code to compile?

```
public static class Crypto
    {
        #region Settings

        private static int _iterations = 2;
        private static int _keySize = 256;

        private static string _hash = "SHA1";
        private static string _salt = "aselrias38490a32"; // Random
        private static string _vector = "8947az34awl34kjq"; // Random

        #endregion

        public static string Encrypt(string value, string password)
        {
            return Encrypt<AesManaged>(value, password);
        }

        public static string Encrypt<T>(string value, string password)
            where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
        {

            byte[] vectorBytes = GetBytes<ASCIIEncoding>(_vector);
            byte[] saltBytes = GetBytes<ASCIIEncoding>(_salt);
            byte[] valueBytes = GetBytes<UTF8Encoding>(value);

            byte[] encrypted;
            using (T cipher = new T())
            {
                PasswordDeriveBytes _passwordBytes =
                    new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, _hash, _iterations);
                byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(_keySize/8);

                cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = cipher.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream to = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream writer = new CryptoStream(to, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            writer.Write(valueBytes, 0, valueBytes.Length);
                            writer.FlushFinalBlock();
                            encrypted = to.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
                cipher.Clear();
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string value, string password)
        {
            return Decrypt<AesManaged>(value, password);
        }

        public static string Decrypt<T>(string value, string password) where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
        {
            byte[] vectorBytes = GetBytes<ASCIIEncoding>(_vector);
            byte[] saltBytes = GetBytes<ASCIIEncoding>(_salt);
            byte[] valueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

            byte[] decrypted;
            int decryptedByteCount = 0;

            using (T cipher = new T())
            {
                PasswordDeriveBytes _passwordBytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, _hash, _iterations);
                byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(_keySize/8);

                cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                try
                {
                    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = cipher.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream from = new MemoryStream(valueBytes))
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream reader = new CryptoStream(from, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                decrypted = new byte[valueBytes.Length];
                                decryptedByteCount = reader.Read(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return String.Empty;
                }

                cipher.Clear();
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted, 0, decryptedByteCount);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
```

Answer (score 2):

That will be

[Encoding.ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).[GetBytes(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

Comment: There is no ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes

Comment: There is Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);

Comment: @user2471435 Yeah, sorry :)