# How to load xml config file from another computer?

Tags: c#, xml, file, security, config

I have application c#, config file is xml file.
If same computer it working is fine but not security.
In this case, everyone can see and read this config file.

Can I load xml file from another computer?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileXml);
var cmds = doc.Root
              .Element("ListProfile")
              .Elements("Profile")
              .Where(b => b.Element("Id").Value == profile_id)
              .SelectMany(b => b.Element("Command").Elements())
              .Select(p => new
               {
                   Id = (int)p.Element("Id"),
                   Path = (string)p.Element("Path"),
                   Value = (string)p.Element("Value")
               });
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the goal? To have one config file in a central location, or to stop people who use your application from seeing the config file?

Comment: To deny users see or read content in xml file.

Comment: string xmlData= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(<network path to the file>);

Comment: In that case, read the last paragraph of my answer. If you have questions about how to encrypt, I can give you some tutorials as well.

Comment: @Toan Nguyen
Wouldn't a computer in the same network just put the problem there? If the computer is accessible through the network any maleficent user can access it anyways, and read the plain text passwords in it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load your config when starting the application, or is it possible to load the config after the initial load is done. In the latter case, you would be better of using a webservice.

Also where is this second PC located? Is it inside the same LAN or somewhere else? Same as with the first point, the latter would make a webservice a better option.

Lastly, what is the security problem. If you are worried about passwords in the config, you could encrypt these passwords, and load the encrypted password from the XML, then just decrypt and see if it's correct.

Comment: Thank for your reply. second PC located is LAN <br/> Can you support me, how to using a webservice with application C#?

Comment: If the second PC is in the same lan, both a webservice and getting the file from said PC aren't advised. Especially if you only want to do this for security reasons, since you'll send everything as plain text.

You're better of just encrypting the sensitive data in your XML.
You could use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp

You only need the decrypt in your application, you can make a simple second application to encrypt the sensitive data from your XML.