# c# aes ctr no IV javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, aes

I'm looking for a import Aes Ctr on c#
I have found this code that working great but it is in Javascript, somebody know if there is corrispettive on c#?

Aes builtin on c# is not the same I have just tried it.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html

I tried this code:
https://gist.github.com/beveradb/db41b9b73a1c8cea7709
but I don't have same output on original javascript.

Thanks for help.

It is not the same of other question ([Using AES encryption in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp)) cause there isn't IV and Key.