# Error "The input data is not a complete block" while Decrypt in MVC

Tags: c#, security, encryption, model-view-controller

```
 public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

> "The input data is not a complete block" error when i try to decrypt 
>   .Error evoke at cs.close();
>   and below is encryption which is work fine

```
 public string encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

Encryption working fine it encrypt string correctly but when i want to decrpt it evokes error

Comment: Can you show us the code that encrypts? What's the Padding and Mode set to on your encryptor?

Comment: @KMoussa i edited question see

Comment: try setting the Padding and Mode to matching values when encrypting and decrypting and see if that helps

Comment: I didn't understand if possible please edit method as you told me

Comment: try setting this `ecryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7` when encrypting and decrypting

Comment: still facing same error

Comment: just noticed you are calling `cs.Write` instead of `cs.ReadBytes` when decrypting .. have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp

Comment: Try Convert.ToBase64String/Convert.FromBase64String instead of using Encoding.Unicode.  You're probably losing something in what the encoding interprets as a control character.