# Convert object values to base64

Tags: c#

I am very new to C#.

```
encodevalues(object)
```

I need to use above function where i have to encode the values of object. Object can be different every time like below

```
{ "name" "Swamy", "email": : "Swamy123@gmail.com }  
or
{"firstname": "Swamy", "lastname": "reddy"}
or 
{"name": "Swamy"}
```

So I want to encrypt the only values and return the object.

How can i do this, please help.

Best,

Comment: Note that *base64 **encoding*** is not *encryption*.

Comment: Did you try anything? Any existing code snippets?

Comment: @Herohtar ok, I've changed the question.

Comment: No, I don't have @Thangadurai

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string

Comment: Now if you wanted to **encrypt** the values, I suggest [using AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Kei it is not related to my question. I know how to encode, but I don't know how to encode the only values in any given object

Comment: @swamy so basically, you want a function that encodes all string properties of any given object?

Comment: Yes, Exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want a function that encodes all string properties of any given object.

To do this, you can use a bit of [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). Note however, that the function below performs the encoding in-place. If you need it to return an encoded *copy* of the original object, you'll need to do some cloning (which can get pretty complicated if you need [deep cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308879/11981207)).

```
public static void EncodeAllProperties(object obj)
{
    var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, Base64Encode(prop.GetValue(obj) as string));
        }
    }   
}

// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743162/11981207
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
{
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```