# How can I encypt a parameter with Rijndael in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, oauth, cryptography, aes

How can I encrypt a parameter variable using the encryption method `Rijndael`?
I would like to encrypt some parameters in order to post them in an API call.
The key should be in a specific form , `1st Key + IV Key`.
In addition , the `1st key` should have a specific format.

If anyone is able to provide a code sample for this, it would be awesome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp or maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#Y2262 (should have more updates)

Comment: @nanu_nana, what should I do if  the 1st key should have a specific format?

Comment: microsoft doc says "This algorithm supports key lengths of 128, 192, or 256 bits; defaulting to 256 bits". AES is a block chiffre and they have fixed key sizes. Generating, storing and deleting cryptographic keys is a complicated topic, I would inform myself before handling such topics

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "specific format"

Comment: @nanu_nana, which is the difference between RijndaelManaged and Rijndael , because in your link you have RijndaelManaged..

Comment: RijndaelManaged is .NET code, Rijndael is a call into Windows. BTW, please don't use Rijndael, use AES instead. AES is the 'official' alg, not Rijndael.